How can I format my ssd?
I've been trying to format this ssd emtec X150 240gb and it wouldn't format. I've tried all types of commands on windows, third-party programs and nothing works. So I downloaded ubuntu on my usb to try to format it with ubuntu. When I use disks app to format it it says "Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (undisks-error-quark, 0). And when I try gparted it looks like it's formating and once it's done nothing changes.

Have you checked the health of the drive?  ie. using it inbuilt SMART capacities; as your provided details (which are limited; we have no idea what Ubuntu product, what release, what kernel stack etc. you opted to try, be it old/new etc) imply a faulty drive, with you ignoring the symptoms.
